# Identity Function: Difference between templates and auto

Tags: c++, templates, auto

I am writing an identity function for some of my classes that keeps a count of its calls (long story -> short: metrics).

At the moment, I'm trying to figure the performance differences/benefits of using a template vs `auto`.

Here is a short example taken from my code of what I'm doing:

```
namespace Metrics {
    unsigned long identifications = 0;
    //auto version
    auto identity(auto i) {
        //... other stuffs
        identifications++;
        return i;
    };
    //template version
    template<class I> I identity(I i) {
        //... other stuffs
        identifications++;
        return i;
    };
};
```

There's a bit more going on, but that is the basics. I know the compiler will just make a function for each, i.e.

```
identity(5);
identity("5");
//generates the functions
int identity(int i) { ... return i; };
const char* identity(const char* i) { ... return i; };
```

At run-time, which one is faster?
And do they have a compile time difference?

Since this function is meant to be called **a lot**, I'm more interested in run-time performance, but there also could be a large amount of types to generate the function for, so I'm also interested in which one would be faster at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

```
auto identity(auto i)
{
    //...
    return i;
}
```

is a shorthand for

```
template <class T>
auto identity(T i)
{
    // ...
    return i;
}
```

which in turn is a shorthand for

```
template <class T>
T identity(T i)
{
    // ...
    return i;
}
```

So no difference whatsoever.

---

Not applicable to your example, but if you are going to use `auto` parameters you need to be aware of some gotchas:

#### `auto` as return type

```
auto foo(auto a)
```

Does **not** mean

```
// not this
template <class T>
T foo(T a)
```

The return type will be deduced from the return expression(s) in `foo` definition, just like any `auto` return type. It just happens that in your function the return type is deduced to be the same as the parameter type.

#### Multiple `auto` parameters

```
void foo(auto a, auto b)
```

Is **not** equivalent to

```
// not this
template <class T>
void foo(T a, T b)
```

but with

```
template <class T, class U>
void foo(T a, U b)
```

Comment: Much appreciated! So to be clear, there's no run-time or compile-time difference between the two?

Comment: @Werlious none whatsoever

Comment: @Werlious You can also check the assembly code or even easier, look at [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/9b890a2d)

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the info, I'll accept your answer after the 10 minute cooldown

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you! I had completely forgotten about cppinsights!